# scanf("%d", &i) won't read numbers with more than 10 digits

Tags: c, io

I am trying to read in an integer of arbitrary size using the `%d` format modifier for `scanf()`. When the input integer has 10 or fewer digits, this action performs as expected. But, when I try to input a number with 11 or more digits, `scanf("%d", &number)` behaves strangely. It seems to return negative values. For example, when `12345678901` is read, the value assigned too `number` is `-539222987`.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this might be? Maybe there's a limit to the size of an integer read by `scanf("%d", &i)`?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a max size that can be represented by an integer, if the string is too big the number might be too big to represent and you will start running into issues.

Comment: `int` is typically a 32-bit value up to 2 billion approximately. For indefinitely big numbers, use a special library like [GMP](http://gmplib.org/).

Comment: How many digits did you expect before trouble occurs?

Answer (score 6):

In most cases in `C`, `int` are **generally** 32 bits, which will only store numbers between `2147483647` and `-2147483648`. Any number outside of the limits won't be supported.

If you want to store longer numbers, you can look into `long long` which are **generally** 64 bits and can store between `9223372036854775807` and `-9223372036854775808`.

You can also make your type `unsigned` so it won't store negative numbers and allocate all values to possitive numbers.

If you want to have absolute control on the number of bits your data type has, you can use [`<inttypes.h>`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/inttypes.h.html). `int64_t` will give you 64-bits of `signed` values and `uint64_t` will give you 64-bits of `unsigned` values.

You can look at the limits of most data types in [`<limits.h>`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/limits_h.htm)

Comment: Note: `long`s are 64 bits on _some_ systems. 32 bit systems and Windows systems typically have 32 bit `long`s, don't assume `long` is guaranteed 64 bits. If you need 64 bit values, `#include <inttypes.h>` and use `int64_t`/`uint64_t` (or `intmax_t`/`uintmax_t`) with the matching `scanf` format defines (`SCNd64`/`SCNu64`/`SCNdMAX`/`SCNuMAX`).

Comment: Since I started composing, you updated to using `long long`, which is better, but really, using the fixed or max width types is far more reliable.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I agree, I have included that in my answer. My originally answer was just trying to answer why his scanf didn't pick up on big numbers so I neglected on that.

Answer (score 1):

An integer type can only store a number as large as the number of bits that are available in that type. The maximum size can be found in `<limits.h>`. Essentially a string with an *arbitrarily* large number of digits can't be stored reliably in a fixed size integer type.

If you can guarantee all input will be small enough to fit you will be fine using a built in fixed width type. However if you need to be able to read in an arbitrarily large integer from a string you may want to look into libraries that exist to do that task. Getting arbitrary precision representations right is a bit complicated so I'd suggest using a library such as [GMP](https://gmplib.org/), in which you may wish to look at this https://gmplib.org/manual/Formatted-Input-Strings.html#Formatted-Input-Strings