# fprintf put random numbers in file

Tags: c

newbie here,
hi,basically im trying to input 10 integers in file, entering less than 9 numbers are correcly written but if im trying to input more than 9 numbers, the contents of the file are random sometimes with negative in the beginning.

what am i missing?

this is the code;

```
int main()
{
    int num;
    int value;
    FILE *test_file;
    test_file = fopen(".\\testfile.txt", "w+");

    if (test_file == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR!\n");
        return 1;
    }

        printf("Enter a number to be written on the text file: ");
        scanf("%d", &num);

        fprintf(test_file, "% d", num);
        fclose(test_file);
}
```

Comment: You mean 9 and 10 digit numbers? Do you understand what the range of an int is? The largest and smallest numbers it can contain?

Comment: If 10 integers I am missing a loop...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39522275/scanfd-i-wont-read-numbers-with-more-than-10-digits/39522305

Comment: You should check if the numbers you enter exceed `INT_MAX` (defined in `<limits.h>`).

Comment: @mediocrevegetable1: no value of type `int` will ever exceed `INT_MAX`.

Comment: @pmg I meant the number that OP tries to input, which is not of type `int` till `scanf` parses it.

Comment: You're using the wrong mode in the call to `fopen`.  Change `"w+"` to just `"w"`.  Using `"w+"` means you're opening it for both reading and writing, which makes no sense here.

Comment: so, you're suggestion **not using `scanf()`** in the first place? Perhaps `fgets()`? :-)

Comment: See paragraph 10 of section 7.19.6.2 of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf.  "if the result of the conversion cannot be represented in the object, the behavior is undefined".    You can represent some 10 digit numbers in a 32 bit integer, but not all of them.  Do you see the problem for 10 digit numbers less than 2147483648?

Comment: "*im trying to input 10 integers*" The code as shown defines tw integers. One is never touched the other is read and written exactly **once**. You might like to change your approch to solve the problem ....

Comment: There no error with this other than `value` is never used, and you're inserting a space at the beginning of your output to file with `% d`, also, you're not ending your output with `\n` so you should use `fflush`, but other than that there is no issue ... so you might want to rephrase your question.

Comment: thanks ya'll now i understand what i miss i guess i should study more about the limits. thanks @WilliamPursell for mentioning similar thread. and actually i mix things up and that code is for displaying the content written in text that's why there is **value** and **w+** sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The limit of int `INT_MAX` is defined as `2147483647`. If you go above that, the number **will** become negative. To avoid this problem, use `long long` or `unsigned long long`. `unsigned long long` can go up to `18446744073709551615` (extremely large).